# "N" option on turntable speed selector

Tags: vinyl, turntable

What does the "N" option on a turntable speed selector mean?  I've seen it on two separate turntables, and it is between the '33' and '45' options.

Comment: My bet is, that it is the pre-LP setting corresponding to 78 rpm (N for normal instead of Long Playing). Should be simple to check...

Comment: @guidot That's a good guess, but I don't think that's it.  One of the record players that has this setting is 70's mickey mouse record player by GE, seen, for instance, in this eBay listing: https://www.ebay.com/i/124052761773?chn=ps&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-117182-37290-0&mkcid=2&itemid=124052761773&targetid=882987571626&device=c&mktype=pla&googleloc=9019537&poi=&campaignid=9248481261&mkgroupid=93494027426&rlsatarget=aud-412677883135:pla-882987571626&abcId=1141156&merchantid=6296724&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIq_Sa_sGQ6AIVEdvACh24HwAsEAYYASABEgIogPD_BwE

Comment: @guidot Unfortunately the one that I have doesn't work and I haven't had a chance to repair it yet, but my son was curious as to what the "N" meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably "Neutral" meaning the motor can be running but not engaged with the platter.  That's useful for cueing up a song (manually putting the needle on the part of the record where you want it to start) so you can spin the platter back and forth freely with your hand.